# What does pay-off mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

Recommender Systems: Noisy data, commercial **pay-off** (e.g., Amazon, Netflix). -- [source](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bonner/courses/2019f/csc411/lectures/01_intro.pdf)

I look up the [longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pay-off). Seems none of the explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's difficult to tell from this context (reading slide presentations without the corresponding audio is usually not a good way of understanding anything), but I suspect that what was actually intended was actually definition #2 from the dictionary entry you linked to:

> if something you do pays off, it is successful or has a good result

In this case, I *think* that they are talking about how well something will do (how much it will "pay off") commercially.  However, it is very difficult to tell exactly what that slide is talking about.